# javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver possible memory leak

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jboss, primefaces-extensions

We recently migrate an application from Jboss EAP 6.1 to 7.1. Our application randomly start to go into a full GC death spiral (avg time 12s stop-the-world) and running out of memory in production environment.

From Jboss EAP 6.1 to 7.1 we migrate

- Java from 7 to 8
- JSF from 2.1(2.1.28.redhat-3) to 2.2(2.2.13.SP4-redhat-1)
- Hibernate from 4 to 5

We also have:

- Primefaces 6.1
- Primefaces Extension 6.1.1 (massive use of DynaForm)

The application works fine in Jboss EAP 6 with PF 6.1 and PFE 6.1.1.

Before JBoss dead we make some heap dump and notice that there are a thread that occupy 3.28 GB in retained heap. 3.27 GB are a java.util.HashMap which each node contains millions of

```
 javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver
```

[image]
We already read this https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/4849 that seems similar to our issue but we don't have the component p:autoUpdate that cause the issue.

## UPDATE 1

I notice that in local environment with downgrade to JSF 2.1 (custom module to JBoss) the number of javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver doesn't icrease exponentially. What change from the two version?

What can cause this memory leak?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The StateHolderSaver is mostly stored in Arrays, not maps - did you find the GC root path to this map or massive StateHolderSaver instances?

Comment: @Selaron Edit the question with screen of heapdump

Comment: But do you have **something** that is updated (the dynaform?)? Or a `p:poll` And can you reproduce on a different environment? Then also try 6.2 or even 7.0 (try, not switch in production)

Comment: @Kukeltje we don't have p:poll and can't reproduce the problem in differrent environment. We do <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form"/> every time component like checkbox, radiobox, calendar etc are used, and we also update the model of the dynaForm.

Comment: ok, but over 3 milion entries??? Did you check if there were changes to Mojarra between the EAP 7.1 JSF version (2.2.11?) and 2.2.19? in this area?

Comment: @Kukeltje i don't find the releases note of mojarra 2.2.x versions

Comment: Add update1 to question

Comment: And if you 'upgrade' to a server with JSF 2.3?

Comment: @Kukeltje if we upgrade to jsf 2.3 we need to make change to application

Comment: Downgrade to jsf 2.1 resolve the problem

Comment: @Kukeltje today we try to switch in production environment to jboss eap 7.3 that ship with jsf 2.3 version but we faces the same exact problem

Comment: Have you tested this on Jboss 7.3 with PrimeFaces 11 and PFE 11.0.4?  I have a feeling its DyanForm related...