# JSF state holder saver memory leak

Tags: java, performance, jsf, memory-leaks, tomcat8

Our app is having frecuent outages so we took a heap dump, because GC was using a lot of CPU, and we find that for the most part, there is a plenty of javax.faces.component.StateHolderSaver instances.

[image]

That image is just one session and the arraylist is storing 49953 instances.
So, using the path to GC roots, we identified the thread:

```
http-nio-8080-exec-184  Runnable Thread ID: 805
  org.omnifaces.cdi.viewscope.ViewScopeStorageInSession$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getBeanStorageId()
  org.omnifaces.cdi.viewscope.ViewScopeManager.getBeanStorage(Contextual) ViewScopeManager.java:176
  org.omnifaces.cdi.viewscope.ViewScopeManager.getBean(Contextual) ViewScopeManager.java:127
  org.omnifaces.cdi.viewscope.ViewScopeManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.getBean(Contextual)
  org.omnifaces.cdi.viewscope.ViewScopeContext.get(Contextual) ViewScopeContext.java:67
  org.jboss.weld.contexts.PassivatingContextWrapper$AbstractPassivatingContextWrapper.get(Contextual) PassivatingContextWrapper.java:78
  org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstanceStrategy$DefaultContextualInstanceStrategy.get(Bean, BeanManagerImpl, CreationalContext) ContextualInstanceStrategy.java:95
  org.jboss.weld.bean.ContextualInstance.get(Bean, BeanManagerImpl, CreationalContext) ContextualInstance.java:50
  org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(Bean, Type, CreationalContext, boolean) BeanManagerImpl.java:694
  org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.lookup(BeanManagerImpl, ELContext, String) AbstractWeldELResolver.java:107
  org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.AbstractWeldELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) AbstractWeldELResolver.java:90
  org.jboss.weld.environment.servlet.util.ForwardingELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) ForwardingELResolver.java:49
  javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) CompositeELResolver.java:62
  com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(int, ELResolver[], ELContext, Object, Object) DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:180
  com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(ELContext, Object, Object) DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:208
  org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(EvaluationContext) AstIdentifier.java:94
  org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(EvaluationContext) AstValue.java:137
  org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ELContext) ValueExpressionImpl.java:184
  org.jboss.weld.module.web.el.WeldValueExpression.getValue(ELContext) WeldValueExpression.java:50
  com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(ELContext) TagValueExpression.java:115
  javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(Serializable, Object) ComponentStateHelper.java:200
  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.isRendered() UIComponentBase.java:470
  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processDecodes(FacesContext) UIComponentBase.java:1258  <2 recursive calls>
  javax.faces.component.UIForm.processDecodes(FacesContext) UIForm.java:238
  com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(VisitContext, UIComponent) PartialViewContextImpl.java:629
  com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(UIComponent, VisitCallback) PartialVisitContext.java:183
  javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(VisitContext, VisitCallback) UIForm.java:405
  javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(VisitContext, VisitCallback) UIComponent.java:1747  <2 recursive calls>
  com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(UIComponent, PhaseId, Collection, FacesContext) PartialViewContextImpl.java:423
  com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PhaseId) PartialViewContextImpl.java:284
  org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialViewContext.processPartial(PhaseId) PrimePartialViewContext.java:65
  javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PhaseId) PartialViewContextWrapper.java:252
  org.omnifaces.context.OmniPartialViewContext.processPartial(PhaseId) OmniPartialViewContext.java:122
  javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processDecodes(FacesContext) UIViewRoot.java:1030
  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ApplyRequestValuesPhase.execute(FacesContext) ApplyRequestValuesPhase.java:79
  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(FacesContext, Lifecycle, ListIterator) Phase.java:100
  com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(FacesContext) LifecycleImpl.java:201
  javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) FacesServlet.java:670
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:230
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:165
  ar.com.dux.jsf.filters.CacheFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) CacheFilter.java:27
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:192
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:165
  ar.com.dux.jsf.filters.SecurityFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) SecurityFilter.java:93
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:192
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:165
  org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) FileUploadFilter.java:89
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:192
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:165
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) WsFilter.java:52
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:192
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:165
  com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) PrettyFilter.java:145
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:192
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:165
  org.omnifaces.filter.GzipResponseFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, HttpSession, FilterChain) GzipResponseFilter.java:183
  org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) HttpFilter.java:108
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:192
  org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) ApplicationFilterChain.java:165
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) StandardWrapperValve.java:198
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) StandardContextValve.java:96
  org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(Request, Response) AuthenticatorBase.java:474
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) StandardHostValve.java:140
  org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) ErrorReportValve.java:79
  org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(Request, Response) AbstractAccessLogValve.java:624
  org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) StandardEngineValve.java:87
  org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) CoyoteAdapter.java:349
  org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(SocketWrapperBase) Http11Processor.java:783
  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(SocketWrapperBase, SocketEvent) AbstractProcessorLight.java:66
  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(SocketWrapperBase, SocketEvent) AbstractProtocol.java:798
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun() NioEndpoint.java:1434
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run() SocketProcessorBase.java:49
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker) ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run() ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624
  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run() TaskThread.java:61
  java.lang.Thread.run() Thread.java:748
```

But I can't relate this to an specific component of the html.
¿How can I identify which is the component causing the issue? ¿Or is more like a general problem of the app?

We are using JSF 2.3, java 8, primefaces 8.0 and tomcat 8.5

Comment: Can you try MyFaces isntead of Mojarra?

Comment: @BalusC I don't have any binding in my app. Already removed those a long a time ago.

Comment: I face the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054020/javax-faces-component-stateholdersaver-possible-memory-leak?r=SearchResults# Downgrade to Jsf 2.1 resolve the problem

Comment: @tandraschko I'm considering MyFaces, for what I've read It does a better job handling memory

Comment: @RoccoN. did you tried myfaces? I dont know if can downgrade to jsf 2.1

Comment: @dssof No i use mojarra

Comment: @Balusc could this be solved by setting STATE_SAVING_METHOD to client?

Comment: @dssof you know how reproduce the problem? Because we face this problem only in production environment and can't reproduce in the other environment

Comment: Nope, I can't reproduce it, we still have this problem.

Comment: @RoccoN. the best solution is to runaway from JSF as soon as possible -.-

Comment: @dssof did you try MyFaces and did it solve the issue.  It's clearly a bug in Mojarra and I would like to get to the bottom of it.